# How to upload multiple files and predefine filetypes?

Tags: 7, forms, files

Does someone know how it is possible to upload multiple files with the [dropbox client](https://www.drupal.org/project/dropbox_client) module for drupal 7?

It would be nice if it could be integrated with [plupload](https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload).

Also i would like to know how i can predefine the filetypes users can upload?

I'm a n00b in php, can someone give me some tips or solutions?

Here is the part of the upload funktion in the dropbox client module.

```
function dropbox_client_upload_form( $form, &$form_state ) {

  $form[ 'upload' ] = array(
    '#title' => t('Upload file'),
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#size' => 20,
    );
  $form[ 'submit' ] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t( 'Upload' ),
    );
  return $form;
}

function dropbox_client_upload_form_submit( $form, &$form_state ) {

  global $user;

  $dropbox = dropbox_client_get_client();

  //Process files
  $uploads_dir = dirname( $_FILES[ 'files' ][ "tmp_name" ][ 'upload' ] );

  $tmp_name = $_FILES[ 'files' ][ "tmp_name" ][ 'upload' ];
  $name = $_FILES[ 'files' ][ "name" ][ 'upload' ];
  $filename = "$uploads_dir/$name";
  move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name, $filename );

  $dpath = (isset( $_GET[ 'dpath' ] )) ? $_GET[ 'dpath' ] : '/';
  $result = $dropbox->add( $dpath, $filename );

  if ( property_exists( $result, 'error' ) ) {
    drupal_set_message( $result->error );
  }
  else {
    drupal_goto( $_GET['q'], array( 'query' => array( 'dpath' => $dpath ) ) );
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Best regards,
meckl

Answer (score 0):

> Also i would like to know how i can predefine the filetypes users can
>   upload?

Specify the file types restriction on the file field with 'file_validate_extensions' in the #upload_validators array in the file field.
See the [form api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) for reference. See the [file_managed](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file) field.